# Incrementing rows in the database

Tags: php, mysql, forms, if-statement

I have a form that adds / edits an event.
Namely, I wanted to extend it with the function of adding value automatically (just like increment and ++).
I have statistic_tips in the database containing two lines: stat_win and stat_false
Only during editing (because in principle the editing will usually consist in changing one record) after making changes, I would like to automatically increase the stat_win or stat_false line depending on the selected option (win, loss from results).
How do you achieve this, my dear?
Prompt? Possibly I would like to hear better solutions with a pleasant desire.
I apologize for a mistaken question, but I am a beginner
In red I marked the fragment, where I tried to figure it out, but unfortunately it failed.

```
 <?php
            function undefinedIndex(){
            }
            set_error_handler("undefinedIndex", E_NOTICE);
            if(isset($_POST['add_tip'])){
              $team1=$_POST['team1'];
              $team2=$_POST['team2'];
              $league=$_POST['league'];
              $datentime=$_POST['datentime'];
              $draw=$_POST['draw'];
              $results=$_POST['results'];
              $sql_insert="INSERT INTO premium_tips(datentime, league, team1, team2, draw, results) VALUES ('$datentime','$league','$team1','$team2','$draw','$results')";
              if ($conn->query($sql_insert) === TRUE) {
              } else {
               echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
             }
           }
           if(isset($_POST['update_tip'])){
                                    $team1=$_POST['team1u'];
                                    $team2=$_POST['team2u'];
                                    $league=$_POST['leagueu'];
                                    $datentime=$_POST['datentimeu'];
                                    $draw=$_POST['drawu'];
                                    $results=$_POST['resultsu'];
                                    $id=$_POST['id'];
                                 [color="#FF0000"]   $win1=$mysqli->query('SELECT stat_win FROM statistic_tips');
                                    $loss1=$mysqli->query('SELECT stat_false FROM statistic_tips');
                                    if($results=="win"){
                                      $sql_insert="
                                      UPDATE statistic_tips (stat_win) VALUES '$win1+=1'";
                                    }
                                    if($results=="loss"){
                                      $sql_insert="
                                      UPDATE statistic_tips (stat_false) VALUES '$loss1+=1'";
                                    }[/color]
                                    $sql_insert="
                                    UPDATE premium_tips SET datentime='$datentime', league='$league',team1='$team1', team2='$team2',draw='$draw', results='$results' WHERE id='$id'";
                                    if ($conn->query($sql_insert) === TRUE) {
                                                                    } else {
                                             echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
                                                                    }
                                                                }
                                                                ?>
```

And here is the file responsible for the editing form

```
     $sql_get = "SELECT * FROM matches WHERE match_id='$q'";
     $result = $conn->query($sql_get);
     if($result->num_rows>0){
     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
     echo '<form role="form" method="post" action="" 
     onreset="resetAction()">
                               <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Match info</label>

                                        <input class="form-control" placeholder="Date of match" type="datetime-local" name="datentime" required><br>
                                        <input class="form-control" placeholder="League" name="league" required><br>
                                        <input class="form-control" placeholder="Stadium" name="stadium" required>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Home</label>
                                        <input class="form-control" placeholder="Enter team name" name="team1" required>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Away</label>
                                        <input class="form-control" placeholder="Enter team name" name="team2" required>
                                    </div>
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="add_match">Add Match</button>
                                    <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default">Reset</button>

                                </form>';
```

In fact, I mean automatic statistics on the WON / LOSS chart
At the beginning, when adding, each type has $ result = actual and when editing it is changed to either $ result = win or $ result = loss
I do not know if he combines well with these statistics.

Comment: If you want to do it from database directly without coding then you can check triggers. http://www.mysqltutorial.org/create-the-first-trigger-in-mysql.aspx

Comment: what is the trigger that will work after modifying the row?

Comment: for modify I assume you mean update, then its: after update. Checkout this link http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-trigger-implementation.aspx

Comment: I'm sitting here for a good few hours and I can not figure out how to do it.
@Oras I will be grateful and even reward paypal :)

Comment: I'm happy to help, no need for paypal. Please post your two tables and your inserting/updating criteria.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE statistic_tips (stat_win) VALUES '$win1+=1'
```

This isn't valid SQL syntax.

What you're looking for is:

```
UPDATE statistic_tips SET stat_win = stat_win + 1 WHERE id = ?
```

Note that you don't need to select the previous value from the database beforehand -- the UPDATE query will increment it in place.

Comment: No errors, but nothing add to statistic_tips.
I even tried with : 
                                          INSERT INTO statistic_tips(stat_win, stat_false) VALUES ('1','0')";